# JQuery Dialog tool bar with drop down button instead of title

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, toolbar, navbar

lI would like to add a Toolbar or nav bar with a dropdown button instead of the title "?ToolbarHTMLCodeHere?" in my JQuery Dialog window. There should be drop down button with the name "File" in the toolbar when the drop down openes there should be a button inside called "Save".

Does anybody know how to do that?

```js
function openDialog(){
        $(function() {          // open popup window
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                create: function (event, ui) {
                    $(".ui-dialog-title").html("?ToolBarHTMLCodeHere?");
                },
                width: 250,
                height: 150,
                modal: true,
                resizable: false
            });});
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="Browse" onclick="openDialog()">Start dialog</button> <!--Create Button-->

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" >
```

What i have until now is this (but its so ugly, hopefully somebody has a better solution):

```js
    function openDialog(){
        $(function() {          // open popup window
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                create: function (event, ui) {
                    $(".ui-dialog-title").html("<div class='actions'><a id='TakeAction'>File</a><ul id='actions'><li>Save</li></ul></div>");
                },
                width: 250,
                height: 150,
                modal: true,
                resizable: false
            });});
    }
```

```css
ul#actions
        {
            display:none;
        }
        .actions:hover ul#actions
        {
            display: block;
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="Browse" onclick="openDialog()">Start dialog</button> <!--Create Button-->

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" >
```

Comment: Not clear what is the problem if you already know how to change `$(".ui-dialog-title")` inner HTML. Just append whatever you need and initialize.

Comment: But i dont know how to insert a down button there.